# How to integrate Angular Cli with .net Angular template

Tags: asp.net, angular, angular-cli

I have chosen to develop with **ASP.NET Core MVC** and I am using the Angular template for the front end (See image below). I want to use this with the Angular Cli to generate components, directives etc. How can I modify the basic template to make it compatible with the **Angular Cli**?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To integrate Angular Cli with VS 2017 Angular ASP.NET template.... (I will place the path that you should be executing these commands on inside brackets at the end of each step. `your_project/` denoting your VS17 project!)

1. Globally install the Angular Cli `npm install -g @angular/cli@latest` (your_project/)
2. Install the Angular Cli in project dev environment `npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@latest` (your_project/)
3. Rename app.module.shared.ts file to app.module.ts (your_project/ClientApp/)
4. Inside the `app.module.browser.ts` file, change `import { AppModuleShared } from './app.module.shared';` to `import { AppModuleShared } from './app.module';` (your_project/ClientApp/app/)
5. Inside the `app.module.server.ts` file, change `import { AppModuleShared } from './app.module.shared';` to `import { AppModuleShared } from './app.module';` (your_project/ClientApp/app/)
6. Now create a new angular project in a folder on your desktop by issuing the command `ng new test`. Once this has complete, copy the angular-cli.json file to the root of your project folder and rename the root field from 'src' to 'ClientApp'. (C:/Users/your_username/Desktop/)
7. Now test that it works by issuing the command `ng g c components/test` (your_project/)

For more detail and image click [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1208529/Angular-CLI-and-ASP-NET-Core-Angular-Template). I've posted it also to ensure the link doesn't become broken!

Comment: now they came up with angular cli template once check.